# reverse proxy on iis to hide part of URI

Tags: iis, web, proxy, url-rewriting, arr

Im trying to implement proxy for a site 
I have :

http://localsite/site1

http://localsite/site2

http://localsite/site3

im trying to create a proxy that will show http://localsite/site1 as http://globalsite1
http://localsite/site2 as http://globalsite2

I found on IIS reverse proxy ability when I add ARR and URL rewrite.

The thing is when I create something like this : http://globalsite1 pointing to http://localsite everything works 
But when I point http://globalsite1 to http://localsite/site1 most of the pictures stop working .
Found out the pictures located under http://localsite/moduls

How can I create a rule that will proxy and hide the /site1 extension but will keep the pictures unchanged

Hope I was clear

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Check the code whether you are using relative paths while specifying image source. If yes you must write an outbound rule to rewrite the image file requests. Use below rule as a reference:

```
<outboundRules>
  <rule name="RewriteImages">
    <match filterByTags="Img" pattern="(.*).jpg$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" value="http://localhost/moduls/{R:0}" />
  </rule>
</outboundRules>
```